# Exponential distribution observing only maximum value and indicator function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am having a trouble solving the following problem.

Find the sufficient statistic of $\theta_x$ and $\theta_y$ where

$x_i \sim \text{Exp}(\theta_x)$ iid $i=1,\ldots,n$

$y_i \sim \text{Exp}(\theta_y)$ iid $i=1,\ldots,n$

and $x_i$ and $y_i$ are independent. but you only observe

$z_i = \max(x_i, y_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$

$\delta_i = I(x_i>y_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$

According to the answer, pdf of $z_i$ and $\delta_i$ is represented as follows:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\theta_x}\right)^{\delta_i}\left(\frac{1}{\theta_y}\right)^{1-\delta_i}e^{\frac{1}{\theta_x}\delta_ix_i}e^{\frac{1}{\theta_y}(1-\delta_i)y_i}$$

and using factorization theorem, the sufficient statistic is given.

But I think the pdf given in the answer is wrong because the integral of the pdf isn't $1$. Am I right? How can I get the right pdf then?

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood function does not really have to be a probability density function in the sense that it should integrate to $1$. See, for example, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31238/119261) popular post on Stats.SE.

As for this particular question, I assume $X_i$'s are i.i.d Exponential with mean $\theta_1$ and $Y_i$'s are i.i.d Exponential with mean $\theta_2$. Suppose $(X_i,Y_i)$'s are independently distributed and that $X_i$ is independent of $Y_i$ for every $i$. Your data is $(Z_i,\delta_i)$ where $Z_i=\max(X_i,Y_i)$ and $\delta_i=I(X_i>Y_i)$.

If $f,F$ be the density and cdf of $X_i$, and $g,G$ be the density and cdf of $Y_i$, then likelihood corresponding to the $i$th observation is

\begin{align}
L(\theta_1,\theta_2\mid z_i,\delta_i)&=
\begin{cases}
f(z_i)P(Y_i\le z_i)&,\text{ if }\delta_i=1
\\ g(z_i)P(X_i\le z_i) &,\text{ if }\delta_i=0 
\end{cases}
\\&=\left\{f(z_i)G(z_i)\right\}^{\delta_i}\left\{g(z_i)F(z_i)\right\}^{1-\delta_i}
\end{align}

So I think the likelihood based on all $n$ observations is

\begin{align}
L(\theta_1,\theta_2\mid \boldsymbol z,\boldsymbol \delta)&=\prod_{i=1}^n \left\{f(z_i)G(z_i)\right\}^{\delta_i}\left\{g(z_i)F(z_i)\right\}^{1-\delta_i}
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^n \left\{\frac1{\theta_1}e^{-z_i/\theta_1}\left(1-e^{-z_i/\theta_2}\right)\right\}^{\delta_i} \left\{\frac1{\theta_2}e^{-z_i/\theta_2}\left(1-e^{-z_i/\theta_1}\right)\right\}^{1-\delta_i}\,,
\end{align}

which is defined for $z_1,\ldots,z_n>0$ and $\theta_1,\theta_2>0$.

This is not a joint pdf of $(Z_i,\delta_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ in the usual sense as this distribution is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. However, if you delve into measure-theoretic details, then this *can* be treated as a density with respect to some dominating measure. For details, see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/248476/119261.